# What is the pipeline DAC tollerable offset from plot

Tags: digital-to-analog

I have analyzed the circuit in full extent as shown bellow.
I know that I showed imagine two-stage back to back and see "which input could handle both".
Could you please show how exactly I get this tolerable offset from this case?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]